# Oracle SQL - finding sets that contain another set

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have a table A that contains a list of a potential employees ID's and their professional skills in the form of a skill code:

```
ID  | skill code
005   12
005   3
007   42
007   8
013   6
013   22
013   18
```

And I have another table B that lists several job position ID's and their corresponding required skill ID's:

```
Job ID | skill code
1        3
1        32
1        21
1        44
2        15
2        62
.
.
.
```

How can I find out which Job Id's a specific person is qualified for?  I need to select all Job Id's that contain all the person's skills.  Say for instance I need to find all job ID's that employee ID 003 is qualified for, how would I structure an Oracle SQL query to get this information?

I want to be able to enter any employee ID in a WHERE clause to find what jobs that person is qualified for.

Comment: You need a simple `JOIN` on `SKILL_CODE`.

Comment: Can you confirm your desired output?

Comment: You don't need the persons which have all the skills for a job but the jobs that have all the skill sof a persons. A little bit weird. In general one wants to find persons that have all necessary skills...

Comment: Your requirements now conflicts each other and the question is put in the Closing queue because is unclear. Why job2 would be a correct option? the user does not have skill 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea would be to count the number of skills for every person and job:

```
SELECT A.id as person_id,
       B.JOB_ID
FROM A
JOIN B
ON A.skill_code=B.skill_code
GROUP BY a.id, b.job_id
HAVING count(*) = (select count(*) from b b2 where b2.job_id = b.job_id);
```

Not tested and assuming that tables are well normalized.

**UPDATE after the OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33605792/oracle-sql-finding-sets-that-contain-another-set/33606173#comment54987299_33605792).** 
It is asked for all the jobs which necessitate all skills of a person:

```
SELECT A.id as person_id,
       B.JOB_ID
FROM A
JOIN B
ON A.skill_code=B.skill_code
GROUP BY a.id, b.job_id
HAVING count(*) = (select count(*) from a a2 where a2.job_id = b.job_id);
```

**Update2**: The question was updated with:

> I want to be able to enter any employee ID in a WHERE clause to find what jobs that person is qualified for.

For this, you just add `WHERE a.id = :emp_id` to the first query. (above group by)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
WITH b1 AS
  (SELECT job_id,
    skill,
    COUNT(*) over (partition BY job_id order by job_id) rr
  FROM b
  ) ,
  res1 AS
  (SELECT a.id,
    b1.job_id,
    rr,
    COUNT(*) over (partition BY id, job_id order by id) rr2
  FROM A
  JOIN B1
  ON A.skill=B1.skill
  )
SELECT id, job_id FROM res1 WHERE rr=rr2
```